# I have script for adding multiple markers to an interactive Google Map. I want all the markers to hold different infowindows

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I have already created the code below. This codes generates a Google Map with different markers. I don't seem to get the code right so that each marker will on mouseclick display a different infowindow. Is there some way to add code in the for loop, so that all markers are built with different infowindows with different content?

```
<body onload="initialize()">

  <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 2,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.241346, 18.281250),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                                    myOptions);

      setMarkers(map, locations);
    }

     var locations = [
       ['AU', -37.850565, 144.980289 , 4],
       ['AS', 48.1670845, 16.3465254, 5],
       ['BE', 50.8826906, 4.4570261, 3],
       ['BR', -23.5004937, -46.8482093, 2],
       ['CZ', 50.0878114, 14.4204598, 1],
       ['DM', 55.6710507, 12.4401635, 6],
       ['FI', 60.2101064, 24.8251788, 7],
       ['FR', 48.8744779, 2.1668675, 8],
       ['GE', 51.19423, 6.70568, 9],
       ['GR', 38.0433281, 23.797971, 10]
     ];

     function setMarkers(map, locations) {
       var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('punaise.png',
         new google.maps.Size(30, 30),
         new google.maps.Point(0,0),
         new google.maps.Point(0, 32));
       var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('schaduw.png',
         new google.maps.Size(30, 30),
         new google.maps.Point(0,0),
         new google.maps.Point(0, 32));

       var shape = {
         coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
         type: 'poly'
       };

       for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
         var entity = locations[i];
         var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(entity[1], entity[2]);
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: myLatLng,
           map: map,
           shadow: shadow,
           icon: image,
           shape: shape,
           title: entity[0],
           zIndex: entity[3],
         });
       }
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's relatively straight-forward; in your for loop you want to init the info window, something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var entity = locations[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(entity[1], entity[2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        shadow: shadow,
        icon: image,
        shape: shape,
        title: entity[0],
        zIndex: entity[3],
    });
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: document.getElementById("overlayContent" + [i]).innerHTML
    });
}
```

The `overlayContent[i]` would get the `<div>` (or other element) with an `id` of `overlayContent1` etc. Then outside of the for loop add a click handler that opens the correct info window:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {

    if (currentInfoWindow) {
        currentInfoWindow.close();
    }
    infoWindow.open(gmap, marker);
    currentInfoWindow = infoWindow;
});
```

The `currentInfoWindow` check ensures only one overlay is open at a time

Comment: thank! Is it possible to add different information to each window in your example?

Comment: Sure, just set different content in each div :)

Comment: Clicking on the markers, does not generate windows. The divs are all displayed nicely under the google map. No running errors.. give your suggestions a try and see (i guess that will be the best to determine what goes wrong)

Comment: The suggestions are working code taken from a live project! Are you sure there are no errors in the console? What browser are you using?

Comment: I use mozilla firefox. Maybe the working code you provided does not interact the way it should with my code? Strange. Have you tried adding your code to mine and then pulling the whole thing in a browser?